# What are the ideal qualities to look for in a supervisor

Tags: discussion

As I write this this-morning I am also submitting an email to my now supervisor advising him that I am no longer continuing to study in the philosophy honours program at my university, and that I have changed to a Masters of Nursing program.

My decision to choose this person was an extension of my estimation of his personal, not professional qualities. Basically he's a top bloke, but I don't value his achievements in philosophy, or his orientation toward philosophy as much as I do other people.

What's more valuable in a supervisor, good character or expertise ?

(please don't say a blend of the two ..)

Comment: This might actually be suitable for the frontpage of the Academia stack

Answer (score 1):

DrSister,

This isn't really the place to post this question, as this is for questions pertaining to Philosophy.SE and/or its management. As posed, I think your question might be a bit too real-world / personal for Philosophy.SE, but it definitely falls under aesthetics in some way. Currently, I think this is a good question to post in chat. Can I encourage you to copy & paste it there, or alternatively, formulate your question in a way that's better fit for the main site by perhaps addressing existing literature or works you've read so far and narrowing down the focus so people can provide real answers rather than purely opinion-based ones? :)